# How to update kubernetes-dashboard with kubespray

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I have no idea how to update my kubernetes-dashboard, its currently version 1.10.2 but i need to update it to Beta 2.0 v8. I'm fairly new to kubernetes, does anyone know how to update? I used kubespray to set up the clusters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all the information [in the repository](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/).

Pay attention to compatibility, version `v2.0.0-beta8` only works with kubernetes > 1.16

Answer (score 0):

I had issues in just moving towards a 2.x.x release as KUbespray creates ressources templated from kubernetes apps role which does not fully match anymore. We disabled the dashboard install in kubespray and just installed in our ansible rollout by the official docs which is fine. Same for helm 3 btw.